# Enable blowfish-based hash support for crypt

Tags: security, debian, hash

How do I enable crypt_blowfish support for shadowed passwords and PHP on a Linux (Debian) server?

I'm referring to the [OpenBSD-style Blowfish-based bcrypt](http://www.openwall.com/crypt/), known in PHP as CRYPT_BLOWFISH.

As far as I know there is no Debian package for it, what other options do I have to enable this hashing algorithm for PHP?

Note:
PHP's [crypt() fuction](http://www.php.net/crypt) interfaces relatively directly with the [C-library crypt(3)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypt_(Unix)#crypt.283.29_under_Linux) function provided by the underlying operating system.

**Update**
Package-naming is not as clear as it could (should) be.
The [PEAR Crypt_Blowfish package](http://pear.php.net/package/Crypt_Blowfish) is a drop-in replacement for PHP's MCrypt extension, allowing for quick *two-way* blowfish encryption.

Also the [Debian BCrypt package](http://packages.debian.org/lenny/bcrypt)  is also an implementation of the 'normal' two-way blowfish algorithm.

What I'm looking for is the Bcrypt-hash implementation for hashing passwords.

Comment: doesn't "pear install Crypt_blowfish" work?

Comment: The pear crypt_blowfish package is the 'normal' two-way blowfish encryption algorithm. I'm looking for the blowfish-based hashing algorithm.

Comment: ah, now I see the problem.

Comment: Didn't know you could have a higher bounty on a question then your current rep. Interesting.

Comment: Rep is deducted immediately, so he had ~200 rep and now has ~50.

Comment: Looks like there's a native implementation of blowfish in crypt() in php 5.3 and up, which is convenient.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The package you need to install in debian is `libpam-unix2`.

Then you will have to edit the following files under `/etc/pam.d/`, and change all `pam_unix.so` usage to `pam_unix2.so`:

- common-account
- common-auth
- common-password
- common-session

Finally, edit `common-password` file and replace "md5" parameter with "blowfish".

Passwords that are updated after these modifications are made will be hashed using blowfish. Existing shadow passwords are not modified. [Source](https://ludovicaelbrecht.wordpress.com/2007/04/02/moving-from-md5-to-blowfish-on-debianubuntu/)

To use blowfish in PHP, you provide a blowfish salt to `crypt()`. Like this:

```
crypt('sting', '$2a$07$' . substr('saltsaltsalt', 0, CRYPT_SALT_LENGTH) )
```

You should first check if CRYPT_BLOWFISH==1. And you'll need to use a long enough salt, which is equal to (or greater than) 22 characters.
[Source](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php)

Comment: Hmmm, after making those changes, CRYPT_BLOWFISH still doesn't equal 1, for some reason.

Comment: A caveat: if your version of pam_unix2 doesn't support the hashing algorithm currently used for a user's password, that user may not be able to log in. I think that's what I ran into on my Debian box; some accounts were using SHA512 and could not log in, but an account that used MD5 could. You can set those passwords from root, because `passwd` doesn't ask for the old password when run from root. **Important: keep your root session open until you're sure you can log in again!**