# Enable bcrypt hashes for /etc/shadow in RHEL, CentOS, or Amazon Linux

Tags: linux, centos, amazon-ec2, redhat, bcrypt

Is it possible to add bcrypt support for system accounts (e.g., in /etc/shadow) in Amazon Linux? (Which is in turn [binary compatible with RHEL5 and CentOS 5](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=194752))

This only *looks* like a duplicate of [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/10585/enable-blowfish-based-hash-support-for-crypt).  The body and accepted answer for that question are Debian specific and don't appear to help me.

Comment: It might have been binary compatible in 2010. But don't count on it being so today.